# Haskell - Returning the number of a-Z characters used in a string

Tags: string, list, haskell

I've been using this page on the Haskell website all day and its been really helpful with learning list functions: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_work_on_lists

My task at the moment is to write a single line statement that returns the number of characters (a-Z) that are used in a string. I can't seem to find any help on the above page or anywhere else on the internet

I know how to count characters in a string by using length nameoflist, but I'm not sure how I would go about counting the number of a-Z characters that have been used, for example 'starT to' should return 6

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @Sibi's perfectly fine answer is to use a combination of `sort` and `group` from `Data.List`:

```
numUnique :: Ord a => [a] -> Int
numUnique = length . group . sort
```

This imposes the tighter restriction of `Ord` instead of just `Eq`, but I believe might be somewhat faster since `nub` is not known for its efficiency.  You can also use a very similar function to count the number of each unique element in the list:

```
elemFrequency :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
elemFrequency = map (\s -> (head s, length s)) . group . sort
```

Or if you want to use the more elegant Control.Arrow form

```
elemFrequency = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

It can be used as

```
> elemFrequency "hello world"
[(' ',1),('d',1),('e',1),('h',1),('l',3),('o',2),('r',1),('w',1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the duplicate elements using `nub` and find the length of the resulting list.

```
import Data.List (nub)

numL :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
numL xs = length $ nub xs
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci > numL "starTto"
6
```

In case you don't want to consider a whitespace in the `String`, then remove it using a `filter` or any other appropriate function.

Comment: `Data.Char` should be useful as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) i'm looking for a way to achieve this just by using one line of code in ghci

Comment: @user2058186 I think it's already one line of code if you remove the type definition.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, depending on what structure you want to use.

If you want to use `Eq` structure, you can do this with `nub`.  If the inputs denote a small set of characters, then this is fairly good.  However, if there are a lot of distinct alphabetic characters (remember that "Å" and "Ω" are both alphabetic, according to `isAlpha`), then this technique will have poor performance (quadratic running time).

```
import Data.Char (isAlpha)
import Data.List (nub)

distinctAlpha :: String -> Int
distinctAlpha = length . nub . filter isAlpha
```

You can increase performance for larger sets of alphabetic characters by using additional structure.  `Ord` is the first choice, and allows you to use `Data.Set`, which gives O(N log N) asymptotic performance.

```
import Data.Char (isAlpha)
import Data.Set (size, fromList)

distinctAlpha :: String -> Int
distinctAlpha = size . fromList . filter isAlpha
```

Answer (score 1):

First, filter the list in order to remove any non a-Z characters; second, remove duplicate elements; third, calculate its length.

```
import Data.Char (isAlpha)
import Data.List (nub)

count = length . nub . filter isAlpha
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numberOfCharacters = length . Data.List.nub . filter Data.Char.isAlpha
```