# Haskell - Return number of chars excluding punctuation and spaces

Tags: string, list, haskell, punctuation

I've just learned how to count the number of chars in a string using `length nameoflist` and I'm wondering if it's possible to count the number of chars without spaces/punctuation?

Any help is appreciated,thanks

Comment: All currently unaccepted answers to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464226/haskell-returning-the-number-of-a-z-characters-used-in-a-string) already mentioned `filter` and functions from `Data.Char` as a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Data.Char

length $ filter isAlphaNum nameoflist
```